# Rails Update Model from Multiple Select Form: No implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

If Project `has_many` Genre `through:` GenresProject

and params are:

```
def project_params
  params.fetch(:project, {}).permit(genres_projects_attributes: [:id, {genre_id: []})
end
```

and my submit form is:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %> 
  <%= f.fields_for :genres_projects_attributes do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.select :genre_id, Genre.order(:id).collect{|g| [g.name, g.id]}, {}, { multiple: true } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update'%>
<% end %>
```

and my params look like this:

```
"project"=>{ ... "genres_projects_attributes"=>{"genre_id"=>["3", "5"]}} ... }
```

Should

```
project.update(project_params)
```

Automatically iterate through the `genre_id` array and create the appropriate GenresProject records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `GenreProject` record, then you will not get an id from the `params`.

Secondly, it will not automatically create the new `Genre` record or update one for you, I think. You should handle creating new record in the `update` action yourself. For example:

```
params[:project][:genre_id].each do |id|
  unless GenreProject.find(id)
    # create new record here
    GenreProject.create
  end
  # other updating operations
end
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I expected, but wasn't sure.